# compare co-occurrence matrices

Tags: r, dplyr, lookup, binary-data

I'm not sure the best way to phrase this and perhaps my goal is easier than I am trying to make it. I'm trying to compare two co-occurrence matrices (MatA and MatB) that have sites as rows and species occuring at each site as columns, 1=present and 0=absent. Here is some smaller pretend data:

```
>MatA
        G. magnirostris  G. fortis  G. fuliginosa G. difficilis
Site1        0           0              1            1 
Site2        1           0              1            1
Site3        0           1              1            0

>MatB 
           G. magnirostris  G. fortis   G. fuliginosa   G. difficilis
Jefferson    1               1           0               0 
Hillsdale    0               1           1               1
```

For each row (site) in MatB, I want to search across each row (site) in MatA and first count how many species co-occur, and if possible track which species.  So for site Jefferson, in MatA that combination of species G. magnirostris and G. fortis never occurs. So the result =0.
For Hillsdale,  the 3 species (G. fuliginosa, G. fortis, & G. difficilis) never occur as all 3, but two combinations do:
 G. fortis & G. fuliginosa, and then G. fuliginosa & G. difficilis.

I should mention that I have hundreds of columns (species) and thousands of rows (sites). I tried a matrix multiplication using MatA %*% t(MatB) as a way to get started but it errors as non-conformable and I don't think thats what I want anyway. Any advice on how to set this up would be very helpful. Been struggling with this for days!

EDIT: I coded a pairwise co-occurrence probability matrix of MatA (MatA.probs). I now want to calculate the combined probability of species matches per row (site) in MatB.  For example:

```
>MatA.prob
                G. magnirostris   G. fortis    G. fuliginosa  G. difficilis
G. magnirostris       NA          0                 1           1
G. fortis             0          NA                 1           2
G. fuliginosa         1          1                  NA          2
G. difficilis         1          0                  2           NA
```

Then given, this the combined probability of the species combination in Jefferson would =0 since that combination never occurs, but in Hillsdale it would be 1 * 0* 2, for each of the three possible combinations. How could I row-wise match the species combinations in MatB to calculate this?

Comment: I'm not sure this is solvable if you care about [all possible combinations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458589/find-all-unique-combinations-for-all-possible-group-sizes) when you have hundreds of columns, even if you only consider the species that are present on each row.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and helping me think this through!  I made some updates, transforming the MatA into a probability matrix.  I think I could then calculate combined probability for each row of MatB. See edit. I'm still now sure how to match colnames to code that...

Comment: I realized you can look at the problem differently, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I realized you don't have to compute all combinations,
here's one way you could do the original problem,
where each row is a sample from `MatB` (or a subset from it) that appeared in `MatA`:

```
library(dplyr)

ans <- apply(MatB, 1L, function(r) {
  matching_names <- colnames(MatA)[r == 1L]
  nonmatching_names <- setdiff(colnames(MatA), matching_names)

  MatA %>%
    filter_at(vars(!!nonmatching_names), all_vars(. == 0L)) %>%
    filter_at(vars(!!matching_names), any_vars(. == 1L)) %>%
    mutate(site_total = nrow(.))
}) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "site")
       site G.magnirostris G.fortis G.fuliginosa G.difficilis site_total
1 Hillsdale              0        0            1            1          2
2 Hillsdale              0        1            1            0          2
```

Comment: Thanks so much! What do you think about trying to modify this using my probability matrix? So instead of a resulting 0/1 table, you could row-wise (or grouping by site) match species ==1 in MatB and multiple all the matching species co-occurrence probabilities from MatA.prob. Then I could group_by site or row-wise multiple across them to get a combined probability.  I love R and dplyr but steep learning curve.

Comment: Sorry, you lost me there with the probabilities, I'm not sure how you computed that last matrix.